# Problem with complex derived type importing to MEF Host app

Tags: c#, mef, composition, importerror

Receiving the following upon call to `hostContainer.ComposeParts()`:

> System.ComponentModel.Composition.ChangeRejectedException
>   was unhandled   Message=The
>   composition remains unchanged. The
>   changes were rejected because of the
>   following error(s): The composition
>   produced a single composition error.
>   The root cause is provided below.
>   Review the CompositionException.Errors
>   property for more detailed
>   information.
>
> 1) No valid exports were found that
>   match the constraint
>   '((exportDefinition.ContractName ==
>   "ModLibrary.IDataHandler") AndAlso
>   (exportDefinition.Metadata.ContainsKey("ExportTypeIdentity")
>   AndAlso
>   "ModLibrary.IDataHandler".Equals(exportDefinition.Metadata.get_Item("ExportTypeIdentity"))))',
>   invalid exports may have been
>   rejected.
>
> Resulting in: Cannot set import
>   'ModAppWorks.Host.DataHandler
>   (ContractName="ModLibrary.IDataHandler")'
>   on part 'ModAppWorks.Host'. Element:
>   ModAppWorks.Host.DataHandler
>   (ContractName="ModLibrary.IDataHandler")
>   -->  ModAppWorks.Host
>
> Source=System.ComponentModel.Composition
>   StackTrace:
>          at System.ComponentModel.Composition.CompositionResult.ThrowOnErrors(AtomicComposition
>   atomicComposition)
>          at System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting.ComposablePartExportProvider.Compose(CompositionBatch
>   batch)
>          at System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting.CompositionContainer.Compose(CompositionBatch
>   batch)
>          at System.ComponentModel.Composition.AttributedModelServices.ComposeParts(CompositionContainer
>   container, Object[] attributedParts)
>          at ModAppWorks.Host.Compose() in
>   C:\Projects\ModAppWorks_2\HostProgram.cs:line
>   83
>          at ModAppWorks.Host.Run() in C:\Projects\ModAppWorks_2\HostProgram.cs:line
>   49
>          at ModAppWorks.Program.Main() in
>   C:\Projects\ModAppWorks_2\HostProgram.cs:line
>   25
>          at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly
>   assembly, String[] args)
>          at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String
>   assemblyFile, Evidence
>   assemblySecurity, String[] args)
>          at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
>          at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object
>   state)
>          at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback
>   callback, Object state, Boolean
>   ignoreSyncCtx)
>          at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback
>   callback, Object state)
>          at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
>   InnerException:

Import snippet:

```
[Import(typeof(IDataHandler))]
public Lazy<IDataHandler> DataHandler { get; set; }
```

However, the DataHandler is defined as such:

```
[Export(typeof(IDataHandler))]
public class DataAgent : DataProvider<SqlConnection, SqlDataReader>, IDataHandler
{
    // contains an empty public ctor passing ctor parameters to DataProvider
}
```

DataProvider is an abstract class that also inherits IDataHandler and actually implements the IDataHandler interface. Also, builds are written directly to an \Extensions directory for the Host app.

Any suggestions as to what I am doing wrong?

Comment: See this blog post for how to debug these types of errors: [How to debug and diagnose mef failures](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dsplaisted/archive/2010/07/13/how-to-debug-and-diagnose-mef-failures.aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I began to suspect that the constructor cannot call a base constructor with parameters. I removed the call to `: base(param1, param2)` and the class will import.

### Edit

Okay, made some more tests with this and it seems that, yes, your class can provide parameters to a base constructor as long as the base class is not inheriting the part to be imported to the host.

Comment: Calling the base constructor shouldn't be a problem, but I don't see any problems with what you've posted.